# Problem printing the lines of a file Java

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

I'm learning how to read and write on files in Java. Made a lot of examples but on this specific case I m having a problem, just don't know why since, as far as I'm concerned, nothing changed compared to the other examples. Maybe there's just a dumb error I can't see. The file with the name "naval.txt" was, obviously, created and saved on the respective source. Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("naval.txt"));
            String line;

            while (((line = br.readLine()) != null)) {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(line);
                System.out.println(sc.next());

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getMessage();
            System.out.println("Not possible to read the file");
        }

    }
```

It doesn't even read it. If I run it it shows the message I wrote for the 'catch(Exception e)'. 
Thank you a lot.

Comment: What is the exception you get? Do a `e.printStackTrace()` in your exception handler.

Comment: In your `while` loop, you could just have `System.out.println(line);` - you don't need the `Scanner`.  But seriously, as jbx suggested, add `e.printStackTrace();` to your `catch` block, so you can see what the actual problem is.  It could be that the file is in the wrong directory, or doesn't have read permission, or something like that.

Comment: you may have an issue with finding the file. lookout for your e.getMessage method. Your are basically just calling a method which returns a String message but you aren't doing anything with it. try indeed the e.printStackTrace() and see what you get for exception. You can also just print the message exception: System.out.println(e.getMessage());

Comment: Thank you. It was indeed a problem reading the file. It's solved. Thank you for all the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing 2 different ways to read a file and the result is wrong.  
There is no constructor for the `Scanner` object, taking as a parameter a string.  
 Just use only `Scanner` to open the file and read its lines:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("naval.txt"));
        String line;
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            line = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }   
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage() + "\nNot possible to read the file");
    }
}
```

Comment: I run the debugger, created all the breakpoints and it doesn't even read the file.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness here's an equivalent solution using just a `BufferedReader`. As noted in other answers, you don't need both the `Scanner` and `BufferedReader`.

```
try {
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("naval.txt"));
   String line;

   while (((line = br.readLine()) != null)) {
      System.out.println(line);
   }
} catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println("Not possible to read the file");
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) The thing is, I ll need each word of the line, that's the reason I had the scanner..

Answer (score 0):

If you are on java-8, the same can be achieved using a single line :

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("naval.txt")).forEach(System.out::println);
```